# scroll to div ajax/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok, for the life of me, I can't get this to work. I've searched for examples and I found tons. But none of them seem to work for me.

Question is simple, I have a `div` that loads content from the database.
I need to scroll to the bottom of the div when the page is loaded.
here's an example.

```
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="messagewindow">
<?php
foreach($results as $r){
//content loop..
}
?>
<div id="scrolltome"></div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

I added the `div` id `scrolltome` in hopes it would work.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle to explain the problem??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply pass the top offset distance of #scrolltome div to body scrollTop on window load like this:-

```
$(window).load(function(e) {
var distance = $('#scrolltome').offset().top
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop:distance},1500);
});
```

Comment: After testing all the other answers, you're answer is the only one i've seen any results too. The only problem with you're answer is, it scrolls the whole page down, But not div id messagewindow. I only need <div id="messagewindow> to be scrolled down. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to scroll page or you want to change the position of the 'messagewindow' div...

Comment: The answer you gave me works perfectly! I was wondering if we could skip the animate part, and have it load at the bottom of the div instead of waiting for it to each the bottom of the div.

Comment: You can change timing here, change 1500 to 0 if you dont want scrolling effect...   $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:distance},1500);

Answer (score 3):

Try using `window.scrollTo(0, $(element).offset().top)`

For example: https://jsfiddle.net/88uhpkx0/

Answer (score 2):

Try below function

```
function scrollToElement(selector, time, verticalOffset) {
time = typeof(time) != 'undefined' ? time : 500;
verticalOffset = typeof(verticalOffset) != 'undefined' ? verticalOffset : 0;
element = $(selector);
offset = element.offset();
offsetTop = offset.top + verticalOffset;
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: offsetTop
}, time);}
```

Call this function by 
`` scrollToElement('#scrolltome`,  750, -50); ``  . Here 750 time set for animate and -50 is elements offset value. You can change these values according to your needs

Comment: Okay, so I tired to use the function you listed above on jsFiddle.. http://jsfiddle.net/7ebakvt2/1/ Here is the link.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your `scrolltome` div is missing `>`.
And you could try the following to make the scroll.

```
    $('#messagewindow').animate({
        scrollTop: divHeight
    }, 1000);
```