# php, scroll page to specified html control on form

Tags: javascript

First question after starting with netbeans and wamp server 2 days ago. Only have some desktop vb background, so my jargon may be off. In vb I would want to set the focus on a control.

I have a long, as in a lot of scrolling, webpage form in html that displays the way I want it. There are about 300 controls, almost all checkboxes.

When the Submit button is clicked at the bottom of the form I want to find any incomplete data, scroll the page to that control and give the user a message so I don't insert unfinished records.

How do I do that?

Comment: They form may be generated by PHP, validation and scrolling will have to be done client side, in Javascript. You should also run the validation server side as well, because the user controls the client.

Comment: Thanks Dan, javascript it is. I had thought i only needed php and mysql when i started, now I'm adding javascript to html and css.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to validate data with javascript and with a function to do scroll. Check this:

[scroll to div ajax/javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30316784/scroll-to-div-ajax-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

In the form, add the 'required' attribute to each input tag. 
EX:

```
<input type="text" required>
```

When the form is submitted, the first input tag with the 'required' attribute will be scrolled to, and the user will be notified.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called validation. You should validate data on the server with PHP to make sure that the data meets your defined criteria (since the data could come from a manipulated form and users can deactivate javascript). You should also look into escaping data, for example with [`mysqli_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) to prevent SQL injection (an attack where a malicious user enters SQL statements in your form to alter/expose data in your database). And you should sanitize your data.

But that is all server-side. What you also want is to have a good user experience and not even send data to the server unless is is valid. This is done with javascript on the client side. The upside is: Immediate feedback without a page load. But it has little to do with security since it's easy to manipulate that or turn javascript off.

I would recommend using jQuery and then a plugin like [jQuery Validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/). And for the scrolling part you could use [jQuery scrollto](https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo). You could combine those two [with a callback](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate) from jquery validation. For example (just a quick and dirty example):

```
$(".form-selector").validate({
  invalidHandler: function(event, validator) {
    // 'this' refers to the form
    var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
    if (errors) {
      var message = errors == 1
        ? 'You missed 1 field. It has been highlighted'
        : 'You missed ' + errors + ' fields. They have been highlighted';
      $("div.error span").html(message);
      $("div.error").show();
      // Now scroll to the first error message
      var first_element = validator.errorList[0].element;
      $(window).scrollTo(first_element);
    } else {
      $("div.error").hide();
    }
  }
});
```

But the best thing would be to start with a jQuery tutorial and then dig into that.